# Importing/Filtering properties in Spring context

Tags: java, spring

I'm using Java 1.6 and Spring 3.1.1.   I'm trying to read external properties files into a Spring context.  Here's the sticking point:  The first properties file contains the path to the next properties file.  Example:

First properties file in ${user.home}:

```
resource.dir=C:/users/smith
config.dir=${resource.dir}/configuration
```

Second properties file ${config.dir} (defined in first properties file):

```
datasource.name=jdbc:mysql://dbserver:3306/test
datasource.prop1=etc
datasource.prop2=etc
```

So I need to read the first file, process those properties, and use them to get to the second file.

Using a Spring PropertyPlaceholderConfigurer only gets me to the first file.   I have read that you can only have one PropertyPlaceholderConfigurer in your app context, and that seems to be true.   [Edit:  See  https://jira.springsource.org/browse/SPR-6428 for an explanation.]

Anybody know the best way to do this?

Edit:  This is apparently easy to do if you are running a build in ant, unfortunately my project uses Maven.   You use the PROPERTY tag to do the first step, and it "automagically" parses everything for the next step, allowing you to set your classpath to the ${cfg.dir} directory, etc.   You can then read properties "normally" from these directories.  I was hoping that Spring or Maven would allow me the same functionality but haven't found the answer yet...

ANT example:

```
<property file="${user.home}/global.properties" />

<target name="run-some-stuff">
    <java classname="com.mystuff.App" failonerror="true" fork="yes">
        <classpath>
            <path location="${cfg.dir}" />
            <path location="${resource.dir}" />
        </classpath>
        </java>
    </target>
```

Comment: This probably doesn't help you, but it *is* possible to have multiple placeholder configurers; you can assign each configurer a different placeholder prefix.

Comment: True, but that doesn't help me in this instance.   I found the explanation for the limitation here:   https://jira.springsource.org/browse/SPR-6428

Answer (score 1):

If the resource dir is simply the user's home dir, you can do the following in xml...

```
<beans xmlns="http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans"
  xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
  xsi:schemaLocation="http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans/spring-beans-3.1.xsd">

  <context:property-placeholder location="file:${user.home}/configuration"/>
</beans>
```

Or if you prefer to do this in code, you can also use the `@PropertySource` annotation

This works because in Spring 3.1, the PropertySource abstraction unifies properties from system properties, environment variables as well as property files.  user.home is a system property.

Comment: Unfortunately that only gets me halfway there - I then need to read the properties file and filter it, replacing the placeholders with "real values" - and then go get ANOTHER set of property files.   Spring seems very unhappy with this.