# Can Spring's PropertyPlaceholderConfigurer read an entire properties file in code, not as a bean?

Tags: java, spring

Can Spring's PropertyPlaceholderConfigurer class read an entire properties file and resolve all the placeholders automatically for you?   I know that the normal method of doing this is to create a PropertyPlaceholderConfigurer bean and do this when the application context starts up, but I'm in a situation where I need to do it before I start up the context.

I was hoping for a convenience method like

```
// Return filtered properties from user input file
Properties getProperties(FileInputStream myPropertiesFile);
```

I don't see anything like that in the Spring docs but I can't tell if that's because I'm looking in the wrong place or it doesn't exist.

Comment: _before I start up the context_ where are you going to use it?

Comment: I actually posted a slightly different take on this that explains it a little better:  http://stackoverflow.com/questions/11957948/importing-filtering-properties-in-spring-context

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Do you simply want to create an instance of the `PropertyPlaceholderConfigurer` give it the location of a load of resource files and then have it create a `Properties` instance containing all properties that it found?

If that is the case there is a `protected` method that you could potentially use.

```
/**
 * Return a merged Properties instance containing both the 
 * loaded properties and properties set on this FactoryBean.
 */
protected Properties mergeProperties() throws IOException
```

So you could create your own custom `PropertyPlaceholderConfigurer` and then use this method to return all properties. i.e.

```
public class MyPropertyPlaceholderConfigurer extends PropertyPlaceholderConfigurer {

    public Properties getAllProperties() throws IOException {
        return super.mergeProperties();
    }
}
```

There might be a more efficient way to do this, but I couldn't find one at the moment. If I find anything else will let you know.

Comment: I tried the solution but couldn't get it to work.   It read the properties but never replaced the placeholders.   Probably my faulty understanding of Spring.   Thanks - I'll keep at it...

Comment: Sorry that it didn't work out as you hoped. Having read your follow up question, we had a similar problem. We ended up writing a custom Ant Task (org.apache.tools.ant.Task) that read in property files and replaced our own custom tokens (using the pattern `@@token.name@@`). We then created a custom maven plugin that simply created an instance of this task and then executed it. We could then include execution of this maven plugin in our module builds as required. A lot of work, but certainly a possibility for you.

Comment: That sounds like the direction I might have to go in.  It's nice to know I'm not the only one who's faced this problem, and that someone's been there before.   Thanks.